# facing issue to create this frame. can any one help me to achieve this

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

i am trying to make this shape from last 3 days, how to make the icon rectangle and the shape
[image]

Answer (score 0):

i have achieved this till now

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<item android:top="20dp"
    android:width="50dp"
    android:height="75dp"
    android:gravity="center|top">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="50dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="50dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="50dp"
            android:topRightRadius="50dp" />


        <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>

        <!--If your shape requires only one solid color-->
        <!--<solid
            android:color="#FFFFFF" />-->

        <size
            android:width="42dp"
            android:height="22dp" />

        <!--Use android:dashWidth="2dp" and android:dashGap="2dp"
        to add dashes to your stroke-->

    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:width="60dp"
    android:height="60dp"
    android:gravity="center">
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="50dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="50dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="60dp"
            android:topRightRadius="60dp" />



        <!--If your shape requires only one solid color-->
        <!--<solid
            android:color="#FFFFFF" />-->

        <size
            android:width="42dp"
            android:height="82dp" />

        <!--Use android:dashWidth="2dp" and android:dashGap="2dp"
        to add dashes to your stroke-->
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>

    </shape>
</item>
```

[image]